# Implementing push notification without prompt message in iphone

Tags: iphone, push-notification

Is it possible to invoke an application without prompt message . I have created a sample application and it need to send request on server after every 15 min and save response. Is it possible to implement this in iphone. If possible, which way shall i do that... please help

Thanks in advance..............

Comment: What do you mean with "prompt message"? Your title is not refering to your actual question!

Comment: Push service is allows you to send alerts (prompt message) to a mobile device. but i don't need this alerts. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `UILocalNotification` let the `alertBody` property empty (it is nil by default) and there will be no alert. [More Information here...](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

If you are using remote push notifications (APNS) you should not include a alert key-value in the notification payload and there will be no alert. [More Information here...](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

But you should consider that using UILocalNotification is device intern only and using APNS is server to device only. Maybe think of using [Executing Code in the Background](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html).